# Message Pop up, how to disable it

Tags: samsung

I am new to Android with a Samsung A70 ( I really like it) but struggling with one element.

Can I stop pop up of WhatsApp and Messages coming on to the phone but still get a notification of the message on my FitBit? 
Its just when the phone is sat there anyone can see the message if its not on Locked Screen